# Given genus $0$ compact Riemann surface, is there a Hauptmodul having pole of order 1 at $\infty$?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma \subset SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ be a discrete subgroup containing the transformation $z\mapsto z+1$. Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper-half plane, and let $X:= \Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}^{*}$ be the compactified Riemann surface obtained from $\Gamma$. Assume $X$ has genus $0$. Can we always find a Hauptmodul (i.e. generator of the function field of $X$) $f$ with ord$_{\infty}(f) = -1$ ?

Comment: What is **your** definition of _Hauptmodul_? Is the reciprocal of a Hauptmodul also a Hauptmodul because if $f$ is a generator then $1/f$ is also one.

Comment: @Somos Let's say an $f$ in the function field $\mathcal{F}$ of $\Gamma \setminus \mathbb{H}^{*}$ which generates $\mathcal{F}$ as an algebra.

Comment: @Somos and yes $1/f$ is one if $f$ is (changed the wording to include Hauptmodul def'n).

Comment: Then $\text{ord}_\infty(f)=-1$ iff $\text{ord}_\infty(1/f)=1.$

Comment: @Somos I was confused on what you said, but then I realized my question was phrased wrongly. I edited. I want to find _a_ Hauptmodul. Now that I think though, $X$ will be homeomorphic to the Riemann sphere right? The meromorphic functions there are all generated by $z$ which has pole of order $-1$ at $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $X$ is a compact Riemann surface of genus $0$, it is equivalent to the Riemann sphere $S$. Let $F(S), F(X)$ be the function fields of these surfaces. Then $F(S) \cong F(X)$. As $F(S)$ is generated by $g: z \mapsto z$ having pole at $\infty$ of order $1$, $F(X)$ is generated by the image $f$ of $g$ and still has an order-$1$ pole at $\infty$.